# How to use "calc" library to sum coordinates?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, coordinates, calc

Why does the following code draw an inclined line? I thought the sum ($(1,6) + (2,0)$) would return a point (3,6).

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel,calc,backgrounds,quotes,angles,patterns,decorations.markings,intersections,arrows,arrows.meta}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgflibrary{arrows}                                                  
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ axis lines = middle,
                xmin = -1,
                ymin = -5,
                xmax = 10,
                ymax = 14,
                domain = -1:10,
                xtick = {1,2,...,9},
                ytick = \empty,
                xlabel style={below right},
                ylabel style={above left},
                x tick label style={below},
                samples = 100,
                axis on top=true,
                xlabel = {$x$}, 
                ylabel = {$f$}
              ]


    \addplot[very thick, domain=0:11] {5 + x};
    \draw[thick, dashed] (1,6) -- ($(1,6) + (2,0)$);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The origin of the axis is not at `(0,0)` of the ambient `tikz` picture,

Comment: You have to use: `\draw[thick, dashed] (1,6) -- ($(1,6) + (axis direction cs:2,0)$);`

Comment: I prefer to create named coordinates inside the axis environment and do all the normal TikZ stuff outside.  Otherwise circles get turned into ellipses, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the pgfplots documentation:

> In order to express relative positions (or lengths), you need to use axis direction cs.

So you have to use:

```
\draw[thick, dashed] (1,6) -- ($(1,6) + (axis direction cs:2,0)$);
```

[image]

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% need for outdated TeX distributions
\usepackage{pgfplots}% loads tikz and xcolor
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usetikzlibrary{babel,calc,backgrounds,quotes,angles,patterns,decorations.markings,intersections,arrows,arrows.meta}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ axis lines = middle,
                xmin = -1,
                ymin = -5,
                xmax = 10,
                ymax = 14,
                domain = -1:10,
                xtick = {1,2,...,9},
                ytick = \empty,
                xlabel style={below right},
                ylabel style={above left},
                x tick label style={below},
                samples = 100,
                axis on top=true,
                xlabel = {$x$}, 
                ylabel = {$f$}
              ]
    \addplot[very thick, domain=0:11] {5 + x};
    \draw[thick, dashed] (1,6) -- ($(1,6) + (axis direction cs:2,0)$);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

**Explanation**

Inside the axis the coordinates use the `axis cs` by default.

From the documentation:

> The effect of `axis cs` is to apply any custom transformations (including `symbolic x coords`), logarithms, data scaling transformations or whatever pgfplots usually does and provides a low level pgf coordinate as result.

The low level pgf coordinate refers to the coordinate `(rel axis cs:0,0)`. This is the lower left corner of the axis area (and not to the origin of the axis). Therefore `axis cs` coordinates are absolute positions in the axis. If you add them you get the unexpected result:

[image]

Code:

```latex
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% need for outdated TeX distributions
\usepackage{pgfplots}% loads tikz and xcolor
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usetikzlibrary{babel,calc,backgrounds,quotes,angles,patterns,decorations.markings,intersections,arrows,arrows.meta}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\tikzset{point/.style={circle,fill=black,inner sep=1pt},>=latex'}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ axis lines = middle,
                xmin = -1,
                ymin = -5,
                xmax = 10,
                ymax = 14,
                domain = -1:10,
                xtick = {1,2,...,9},
                ytick = \empty,
                xlabel style={below right},
                ylabel style={above left},
                x tick label style={below},
                samples = 100,
                axis on top=true,
                xlabel = {$x$}, 
                ylabel = {$f$},
              ]
    \addplot[very thick, domain=0:11] {5 + x};
    \path
      (1,6) coordinate(P) node[point,label=above:P]{}
      (2,0) coordinate(Q) node[point,label=above left:Q]{}
      (rel axis cs:0,0) node{x}
    ;
    \draw[blue!50!black] (1,6) -- ($(1,6) + (2,0)$);
  \end{axis}
  \path (0,0) coordinate(O) node[point,label=below:O]{};% origin of the rel axis cs
  \begin{scope}[->,red]
    \draw (O)--(P);
    \draw (O)--(Q);
    \draw (Q)--+(P)node[point]{};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This can be fixed using either

```
\draw[thick, dashed] (1,6) -- ($(1,6) + (axis direction cs:2,0)$);
```

or

```
\draw[thick,dashed] (1,6) -- ($(1,6) + (2,0)-(0,0)$);
```

[image]

Code:

```latex
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% need for outdated TeX distributions
\usepackage{pgfplots}% loads tikz and xcolor
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\usetikzlibrary{babel,calc,backgrounds,quotes,angles,patterns,decorations.markings,intersections,arrows,arrows.meta}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}

\tikzset{point/.style={circle,fill=black,inner sep=1pt},>=latex'}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ axis lines = middle,
                xmin = -1,
                ymin = -5,
                xmax = 10,
                ymax = 14,
                domain = -1:10,
                xtick = {1,2,...,9},
                ytick = \empty,
                xlabel style={below right},
                ylabel style={above left},
                x tick label style={below},
                samples = 100,
                axis on top=true,
                xlabel = {$x$}, 
                ylabel = {$f$},
                clip=false
              ]
    \addplot[very thick, domain=0:11] {5 + x};
    \draw[thick,blue!50!black] (1,6) -- ($(1,6) + (2,0)$);
    \draw[thick,green!50!black] (1,6) -- ($(1,6) + (2,0)-(0,0)$);
    \draw[thick,dashed] (1,6) -- ($(1,6) + (axis direction cs:2,0)$);
    %
    \path
      (rel axis cs:0,0) coordinate(O) node[point,label=below:O]{}
      (0,0) coordinate(A) node[point,label=above left:A]{}
      (1,6) coordinate(P) node[point,label=above:P]{}
      (2,0) coordinate(Q) node[point,label=above left:Q]{}
    ;
    \begin{scope}[->,red]
      \draw[thick,dotted,cyan] (A)--(O);
      \draw (O)--(P);
      \draw (O)--(Q);
      \draw (Q)--+(P)node[point]{};
      \draw[thick,cyan] (Q) ++(P)-- +($(O)-(A)$)node[point]{};
    \end{scope}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I see, thanks! Could you explain, why first (1,6) and first (1,6) inside $$ environment are related to expected cs, but we have to use "axis direction cs" for (2,0)?

Comment: See the explanation in my updated answer.

Comment: ```Inside the axis the coordinates use the axis cs by default. axis cs coordinates are absolute positions in the axis```


inside axis environment (1,6) - point on the Oxy axis plane, where I want.
inside axis environment (2,0) - point on the Oxy axis plane, where I want.
(1,6) + (2,0) = (3,6) - that's how + works in calc.
and inside axis environment (3,6) - point on the Oxy axis plane, where I want.

Where am I not right? Why does + interpret first term in axis plane, but second - in rel axis cs (if I understand the explanation right)?

Comment: `(1,6)` is the vector from  `(rel axis cs:0,0)` to `(axis cs:1,6)` and `(2,0)` is the vector from `(rel axis cs:0,0)` to `(axis cs:2,0)`. Note that `(rel axis cs:0,0)` is not the origin of the axis. It differs from `(axis cs:0,0)`. But you want to add the vector from `(axis cs:0,0)` to `(axis cs:2,0)` to the point `(1,6)`.

Comment: Of course you could also use `($(axis direction cs:1,6) + (2,0)$)` or `($(0,0)+(axis direction cs:1,6) + (axis direction cs:2,0)$)` or `($(1,6)+(2,0)-(0,0)$)`.

Comment: Thanks, I got the idea. But now I wonder, what is the motivation behind considering (1,6) as the vector from different cs: from ```(rel axis cs:0,0)``` to ```(axis cs:1,6)```? Why not ```(rel axis cs:0,0)``` to ```(rel axis cs:1,6)``` or from  ```(axis cs:0,0)``` to ```(axis cs:1,6)``` depending on environment?

Comment: Normally you want the absolute coordinate `(axis cs:1,6)` to plot a curve. This coordinate is transformed in a low level pgf coordinate. The origin for this low level coordinates is `(rel axis cs:0,0)`. If you need a direction (vector), then you have to state what you want: `(axis direction cs:1,6)` corresponds to the vector from `(axis cs:0,0)` to `(axis cs:1,6)`. Note that `(rel axis cs:1,6)` is a point outside of the axis area, because `(rel axis cs:1,1)` is its upper right corner.

Comment: I still don't get it. Let's consider ```\draw[blue!50!black] (1,6) -- ($(1,6) + (2,0)$);```. First (1,6), as we can see, is taken as expected (coordinates along axes on the picture). But $(1,6)$ is not!?

Answer (score 3):

For a better idea what is going on, the coordinate (axis cs: 2,0) is the distance from (rel axis cs: 0,0). not (axis cs: 0,0).  The extra 5 in the y direction comes from [ymin=-5].

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel,calc,backgrounds,quotes,angles,patterns,decorations.markings,intersections,arrows,arrows.meta}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgflibrary{arrows}                                                  
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[ axis lines = middle,
                xmin = -1,
                ymin = -5,
                xmax = 10,
                ymax = 14,
                domain = -1:10,
                xtick = {1,2,...,9},
                ytick = \empty,
                xlabel style={below right},
                ylabel style={above left},
                x tick label style={below},
                samples = 100,
                axis on top=true,
                xlabel = {$x$}, 
                ylabel = {$f$}
              ]


    \addplot[very thick, domain=0:11] {5 + x};
    \coordinate (A) at (1,6);% axis cs: is the default
    \coordinate (B) at (2,0);
    \coordinate (origin) at (0,0);
  \end{axis}
  \draw[thick, dashed] (A) -- ($(A) + (B) - (origin)$);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks! but now I'm a bit confused. I thought, that if you gonna draw plots, you'll work only inside {axis}. What's the common idea, what you will code inside axis environment, and what outside of it?

Comment: The axis cs: coordinates are only available inside the axis environment, but it also does some nasty things to TikZ commands (less now than it used to).  At one point we had to use \pgfplotsextra every time we wanted to use \draw etc.